# Flash drives won't work on USB port but keyboard and mouse works fine

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, usb, usb-flash-drive

I have 2 flash drives 8gb and 64gb work fine on other computers. So I've been my scratching my head all day already about this. I even tried reformatting it but still, the flash drives keep on reconnecting and disconnecting. I am not talking about 15 or 20 minutes interval of disconnecting and reconnecting. It rapidly does this cycle in a second or just two. Kindly check the gifs I attached how my screen looks like.

I already tried steps like updating all the drivers of USB from device manager, switching from different USB ports, and even reformat my PC. Now, even on my fresh win7 and minutes after upgraded to win10 pc it still keeps on disconnecting. Here's how it looks like

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkFRn.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9sLS.jpg

Comment: do the flash drives work on another computer? sounds like your USB ports can't provide enough power - just an assumption..

Comment: yep they completely work fine on laptops and TVs. The usb ports used to work a year ago, wasn't able to turn on this pc i think for 6~8 months already